# Tensorflow GradientBoostedDecisionTreeClassifier error : "Dense float feature must be a matrix"

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-transform

I am getting the error:

**“tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dense float feature must be a matrix.”** when training with estimator **tensorflow.contrib.boosted_trees.estimator_batch.estimator.GradientBoostedDecisionTreeClassifier**. I am using Tensorflow version 1.4.0. The same code works correctly if I change estimator to tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier. In the code, dictionary of features are passed in “Train_input_fn” in tf.contrib.learn.Experiment.

Anyone faced similar error before?

```
#'tensorflow==1.4.0'

import tensorflow as tf
import argparse
import sys
import os
from tensorflow.contrib.boosted_trees.estimator_batch.estimator import GradientBoostedDecisionTreeClassifier
from tensorflow.contrib.boosted_trees.proto import learner_pb2
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import metadata_io
from tensorflow_transform.saved import input_fn_maker
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import learn_runner

RAW_METADATA_DIR="raw_metadata"
CONTRACTED_METADATA_DIR="contracted_metadata"
TRANSFORMED_METADATA_DIR="transformed_metadata"

TRANSFORMED_TRAIN_DATA_FILE_PREFIX="train"
TRANSFORMED_EVAL_DATA_FILE_PREFIX="eval"
DATA_FILE_SUFFIX=".tfrecord.gz"
TRANSFORM_FN_DIR="transform_fn"
TARGET_FEATURE_COLUMN='target_field'

FEATURE_NUMERICAL_COLUMN_NAMES = [
  'feature1',
  'feature2',
  'feature3',
  'feature4',
  'feature5'
  ]

FEATURE_INTEGER_COLUMN_NAMES = [ # comment out fields that are not features
  'feature6',
  'feature7',
  'feature8',
  'feature9',
  'feature10'
]

def _parse_arguments(argv):
  """Parses command line arguments."""
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      description="Runs training on data.")
  parser.add_argument(
      "--model_dir", required=True, type=str,
      help="The directory where model outputs will be written")
  parser.add_argument(
      "--input_dir", required=True, type=str,
      help=("GCS or local directory containing tensorflow-transform outputs."))
  parser.add_argument(
      "--batch_size", default=30, required=False, type=int,
      help=("Batch size to use during training."))
  parser.add_argument(
      "--num_epochs", default=100, required=False, type=int,
      help=("Number of epochs through the training set"))
  args, _ = parser.parse_known_args(args=argv[1:])
  return args

def get_eval_metrics():
    return {
        "accuracy":
            tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
                metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy,
                prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
        "precision":
            tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
                metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision,
                prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
        "recall":
            tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
                metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall,
                prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES)
        }

def read_and_decode_single_record(input_dir, num_epochs,
        mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN):
  if mode == tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
      num_epochs = num_epochs
      file_prefix = TRANSFORMED_TRAIN_DATA_FILE_PREFIX
  else:
      num_epochs = 1
      file_prefix = TRANSFORMED_EVAL_DATA_FILE_PREFIX

  transformed_metadata = metadata_io.read_metadata(os.path.join(input_dir,
      TRANSFORMED_METADATA_DIR))
  input_file_names = tf.train.match_filenames_once(os.path.join(input_dir,
      '{}*{}'.format(file_prefix, DATA_FILE_SUFFIX)))
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(input_file_names,
          num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)

  reader = tf.TFRecordReader(options=tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions(
      tf.python_io.TFRecordCompressionType.GZIP))
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized = serialized_example,
      features=transformed_metadata.schema.as_feature_spec()
  )
  return features

def read_dataset(input_dir, num_epochs, batch_size, mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN):
  def _input_fn():
    min_after_dequeue = 10000
    features = read_and_decode_single_record(input_dir, num_epochs, mode)
    features = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            tensors=features,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,
            capacity=(min_after_dequeue + 3) * batch_size)
    target = features.pop(TARGET_FEATURE_COLUMN)
    return features, target
  return _input_fn


def specify_feature_columns():
    feature_columns = [
        tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(column_name = column_name)
        for column_name in FEATURE_NUMERICAL_COLUMN_NAMES]
    feature_columns.extend([
        tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(column_name = column_name)
        for column_name in FEATURE_INTEGER_COLUMN_NAMES])
    return feature_columns

def build_estimator(model_dir, config, params):
    print "Using gradient boosted decision trees estimator \n"
    learner_config = learner_pb2.LearnerConfig()
    learner_config.learning_rate_tuner.fixed.learning_rate = 0.1
    learner_config.regularization.l1 = 0.0
    learner_config.regularization.l2 = 4.0 / params.batch_size
    learner_config.constraints.max_tree_depth = 4
    learner_config.growing_mode = learner_pb2.LearnerConfig.WHOLE_TREE
    return GradientBoostedDecisionTreeClassifier(
        learner_config=learner_config,
        examples_per_layer=params.batch_size,
        num_trees=100,
        center_bias=False,
        feature_columns=specify_feature_columns()
        # feature_engineering_fn=feature_engineering_fn
        )

def get_experiment_fn(args):
    config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=1000)
    def experiment_fn(output_dir):
      return tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
            estimator = build_estimator(model_dir = output_dir,
                                              config = config,
                                              params = args),
            train_input_fn = read_dataset(args.input_dir,
                args.num_epochs, args.batch_size,
                mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN),
            eval_input_fn = read_dataset(args.input_dir,
                args.num_epochs, args.batch_size,
                mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.EVAL),
            eval_metrics = get_eval_metrics())
    return experiment_fn

def run(args):
    learn_runner.run(get_experiment_fn(args), args.model_dir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = _parse_arguments(sys.argv)
    run(args)
```

The full error trace:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /var/folders/mg/sd4_qlyj4_lbh5ggfn6frvcr00fk8_/T/tmpPFhins
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py:267: __init__ (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.monitors) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-05.
Instructions for updating:
Monitors are deprecated. Please use tf.train.SessionRunHook.
WARNING:tensorflow:Casting <dtype: 'int64'> labels to bool.
WARNING:tensorflow:Casting <dtype: 'int64'> labels to bool.
WARNING:tensorflow:Error encountered when serializing resources.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef.
'_Resource' object has no attribute 'name'
2017-11-16 13:38:39.919664: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
WARNING:tensorflow:Error encountered when serializing resources.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef.
'_Resource' object has no attribute 'name'
2017-11-16 13:38:48.810825: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Dense float feature must be a matrix.
2017-11-16 13:38:48.810825: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Dense float feature must be a matrix.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./trainer/task.py", line 162, in <module>
    run(args)
  File "./trainer/task.py", line 157, in run
    learn_runner.run(get_experiment_fn(args), args.model_dir)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 218, in run
    return _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 46, in _execute_schedule
    return task()
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 625, in train_and_evaluate
    self.train(delay_secs=0)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 367, in train
    hooks=self._train_monitors + extra_hooks)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 812, in _call_train
    monitors=hooks)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 480, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1040, in _train_model
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([model_fn_ops.train_op, model_fn_ops.loss])
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 521, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 892, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 967, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 952, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1024, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 827, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dense float feature must be a matrix.
     [[Node: gbdt_1/GradientTreesPartitionExamples = GradientTreesPartitionExamples[num_dense_float_features=10, num_sparse_float_features=0, num_sparse_int_features=0, use_locking=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ensemble_model, shuffle_batch:16, shuffle_batch:18, shuffle_batch:20, shuffle_batch:21, shuffle_batch:22, shuffle_batch:23, shuffle_batch:24, shuffle_batch:25, shuffle_batch:26, shuffle_batch:27, ^gbdt_1/TreeEnsembleStats)]]

Caused by op u'gbdt_1/GradientTreesPartitionExamples', defined at:
  File "./trainer/task.py", line 162, in <module>
    run(args)
  File "./trainer/task.py", line 157, in run
    learn_runner.run(get_experiment_fn(args), args.model_dir)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 218, in run
    return _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 46, in _execute_schedule
    return task()
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 625, in train_and_evaluate
    self.train(delay_secs=0)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 367, in train
    hooks=self._train_monitors + extra_hooks)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 812, in _call_train
    monitors=hooks)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 480, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 986, in _train_model
    model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1202, in _get_train_ops
    return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1166, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/estimator_batch/model.py", line 98, in model_builder
    predictions_dict = gbdt_model.predict(mode)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/python/training/functions/gbdt_batch.py", line 463, in predict
    ensemble_stamp, mode)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/python/training/functions/gbdt_batch.py", line 392, in _predict_and_return_dict
    use_locking=True)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/python/ops/gen_prediction_ops.py", line 117, in gradient_trees_partition_examples
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/amolsharma/anaconda/envs/oldpython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Dense float feature must be a matrix.
     [[Node: gbdt_1/GradientTreesPartitionExamples = GradientTreesPartitionExamples[num_dense_float_features=10, num_sparse_float_features=0, num_sparse_int_features=0, use_locking=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ensemble_model, shuffle_batch:16, shuffle_batch:18, shuffle_batch:20, shuffle_batch:21, shuffle_batch:22, shuffle_batch:23, shuffle_batch:24, shuffle_batch:25, shuffle_batch:26, shuffle_batch:27, ^gbdt_1/TreeEnsembleStats)]]
```

Comment: what args are you passing in?

Comment: @aug2uag Comment from Soroush helped solve the issue. Had to transpose the features in the input_fun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that the parsing spec created by tf.transform is different from what we normally get. 
Can you share the output of transformed_metadata.schema.as_feature_spec()?

As a work-around try adding this line to your input_fn after features = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...):

`features = {feature_name: tf.reshape(feature_value, [-1, 1]) for
            feature_name, feature_value in features.items()}`

Comment: Thanks @soroush-radpour. As you mentioned above, transposing just after tf.train.shuffle_batch helped solve the problem.